# Get the default Ubuntu-styled layout of GNOME after upgrading from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 but the upgraded Ubuntu doesn't offer the same layout of a fresh installation. So what shall I do to get the default layout of Ubuntu instead of GNOME's default layout?

How my GNOME layout looks like:
[image: How My Gnome Layout Looks Like]

How clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation looks like:
[image: How clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Installation Looks Like]
<sub>(source: [ubuntu.com](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/es6-bundled/src/codelabs/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu/img/4b1f3adbb201b6e1.png))</sub>

The Ubuntu dock is missing. Though I have installed `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`, it is not showing up in GNOME Tweaks.

Comment: @pomsky I have tried ```apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop``` and the default Ubuntu-styled Gnome layout is restored. Maybe I have asked a low-quality question so shall I delete this?

Comment: It might be useful to other users with the same issue. So please consider posting your solution as an answer below by clicking the 'Answer your question' button instead. It's absolutely fine (and very much encouraged) to [self-answer your question](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

may restore the default Ubuntu-styled GNOME layout.

<sub>(Source: [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169704/get-the-default-ubuntu-styled-layout-of-gnome-after-upgrading-from-16-04-lts-to#comment1952760_1169704))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### Case 1

Unity is discontinued since 17.10 release and was replaced by Gnome.
You can follow [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/.) if you want to install unity on 18.04 if that's the case.

### Case 2

If you have stock Gnome. Make sure you have **ubuntu-session** package installed.

1. `sudo apt install ubuntu-session`

*You will need to log out or restart your device for changes to take effect*

2. Click on ***gear icon*** and choose ***ubuntu*** before logging back in again